# Restart of Windows Event Log service crashes my own windows service

Tags: c#, crash, windows-services, event-log, unhandled-exception

I have windows service which uses the C# EventLog class (System.Diagnostics.EventLog). When I restart the Windows Event Log service my own service crashes, even if i'm not writing to the log at the same time. I can catch the exception with 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
 but it gets there with IsTerminating=True and then the service crashes.

I guess it happens because the EventLog class is listening in background. I want to find a way to catch this exception and keep my windows service up without the option to use this class till the next time it will start.

The stack trace of the unhandled exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The interface is unknown
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.get_EntryCount()
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CompletionCallback(Object context)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.StaticCompletionCallback(Object context, Boolean wasSignaled)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context_f(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
```

Comment: What do you mean with it is *Listening*? Did you subscribe to one of the events of the EventLog?

Comment: Yes. I've registered to "EntryWritten" event. But this issue reproduced event without registering to this event.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace from that exception you catched in that UnhandledException event?

Comment: Sure, added to the original post

Comment: Is this service compiled for .Net 2.0? If so, can you try to compile it for .Net 4.0 and see if you can still reproduce it?

Comment: The weird thing is that `CompletionCallback` is guarded with a `catch(Exception)` so it is somewhat unexpected that the Win32Exception isn't caught, and ignored.

Comment: It's compiled in .Net 3.5 and I can't use 4.0 because I need it to run on XP. I'll make a try

Comment: Are you certain it's actually within a try/catch block and that you're catching Win32 exceptions? It would be extremely rare that the exception  handler actually fails to trap an exception. I don't think I've ever seen this. If you're using unmanaged Win32 calls, I don't believe they actually raise exceptions.